# How can I install libgluezilla on Ubuntu 8.04?

Tags: ubuntu, mono

I want to use the Web Browser control within an mono application, but when I do get the error "libgluezilla not found. To have webbrowser support, you need libgluezilla installed."  Installing the Intrepid Deb causes any application that references the web browser control to crash on startup with : 'Thread (nil) may have been prematurely finalized'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
apt-cache search libgluezilla
libmono-mozilla0.1-cil - Mono Mozilla library
```

From the package description:

```
Description: Mono Mozilla library
 Mono is a platform for running and developing applications based on the
 ECMA/ISO Standards. Mono is an open source effort led by Novell.
 Mono provides a complete CLR (Common Language Runtime) including compiler and
 runtime, which can produce and execute CIL (Common Intermediate Language)
 bytecode (aka assemblies), and a class library.
 .
 This package contains the implementation of the WebControl class based on the
 Mozilla engine using libgluezilla.
Homepage: http://www.mono-project.com/
```

You'll probably need to uninstall anything that came in from intrepid without being properly backported.

Answer (score 0):

here's a link to it on the ubuntu site:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/intrepid/libgluezilla

there is a download section at the bottom for a deb package

Answer (score 0):

After installing the DEB that John pointed to, my app crashes...  Is this because the deb is for the wrong Ubuntu (8.08 rather than 8.04)?  It appears to be the correct version of libgluezilla for the version of Mono (everything is. 1.9.1)...

Here is what I get when I try to run the application with

```
$MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug mono TestbedCSharp.exe


Mono-INFO: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Mozilla/0.2.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Mozilla.dll'.
Mono-INFO: Image addref Mono.Mozilla 0x8514cb0 -> /usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Mozilla/0.2.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Mozilla.dll 0x8514590: 2

Mono-INFO: Assembly Ref addref Mono.Mozilla 0x8514cb0 -> mscorlib 0x823ba30: 10

Mono-INFO: Assembly Mono.Mozilla 0x8514cb0 added to domain TestbedCSharp.exe, ref_count=1

Mono-INFO: AOT failed to load AOT module /usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Mozilla/0.2.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Mozilla.dll.so: /usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Mozilla/0.2.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Mozilla.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono-INFO: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Mozilla/0.2.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Mozilla.dll'.
Mono-INFO: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Mozilla/0.2.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Mozilla.dll.config'.
Mono-INFO: Config attempting to parse: '/etc/mono/assemblies/Mono.Mozilla/Mono.Mozilla.config'.
Mono-INFO: Config attempting to parse: '/home/kris/.mono/assemblies/Mono.Mozilla/Mono.Mozilla.config'.
Mono-INFO: Assembly Ref addref System.Windows.Forms 0x82880d8 -> Mono.Mozilla 0x8514cb0: 2

Mono-INFO: Assembly Ref addref Mono.Mozilla 0x8514cb0 -> System 0x8290908: 5

Mono-INFO: DllImport attempting to load: 'gluezilla'.
Mono-INFO: DllImport loading location: 'libgluezilla.so'.
Mono-INFO: Searching for 'gluezilla_init'.
Mono-INFO: Probing 'gluezilla_init'.
Mono-INFO: Found as 'gluezilla_init'.

** (TestbedCSharp.exe:22700): WARNING **: Thread (nil) may have been prematurely finalized
```